# Json Serialization for Trait with Multiple Case Classes (Sum Types) in Scala's Play

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework-2.0

I often have to serialize/deserialize sum types (like `Either[S,T]`), and I haven't yet found a general or elegant way to do it.  Here's an example type (essentially equivalent to `Either`)

```
sealed trait OutcomeType
case class NumericOutcome(units: String)              extends OutcomeType
case class QualitativeOutcome(outcomes: List[String]) extends OutcomeType
```

Here's my best effort at a companion object that implements serialization.  It works, but it's very tiresome to write these sorts of things over and over for every sum type.  Are there any suggestions for making it nicer and/or more general?

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

object OutcomeType {

  val fmtNumeric     = Json.format[NumericOutcome]
  val fmtQualitative = Json.format[QualitativeOutcome]

  implicit object FormatOutcomeType extends Format[OutcomeType] {
    def writes(o: OutcomeType) = o match {
      case n@NumericOutcome(_)     => Json.obj("NumericOutcome"     -> Json.toJson(n)(fmtNumeric))
      case q@QualitativeOutcome(_) => Json.obj("QualitativeOutcome" -> Json.toJson(q)(fmtQualitative))
    }

    def reads(json: JsValue) = (
      Json.fromJson(json \ "NumericOutcome")(fmtNumeric) orElse
      Json.fromJson(json \ "QualitativeOutcome")(fmtQualitative)
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried json4s http://json4s.org ?
Also if you want to use it with play then you should look here: https://github.com/tototoshi/play-json4s
or implement this yourself.

Comment: Looks nice to me. Could you update your best effort to play2.5? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I found out how to do this in play2.5 and put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is about as simple as you can make it, if you want to avoid writing the code for each explicit subtype maybe you could do it with reflection, use jackson directly or some other json library with reflection support. Or write your own macro to generate the Format from a list of subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a systematic solution for the problem of serializing sum-types in my json pickling library [Prickle](https://github.com/benhutchison/prickle). Similar ideas could be employed with Play. There is still some config code required, but its high signal/noise, eg final code like:

`implicit val fruitPickler = CompositePickler[Fruit].concreteType[Apple].concreteType[Lemon]`

[CompositePicklers](https://github.com/benhutchison/prickle#support-for-class-hierarchies-and-sum-types) associated with a supertype are configured with one `PicklerPair` for each known subtype (ie sum type option). The associations are setup at configure time.

During [pickling](https://github.com/benhutchison/prickle/blob/master/shared/src/main/scala/prickle/CompositePicklers.scala#L22) a descriptor is emitted into the json stream describing which subtype the record is.

During [unpickling](https://github.com/benhutchison/prickle/blob/master/shared/src/main/scala/prickle/CompositePicklers.scala#L58), the descriptor is read out of the json and then used to locate the appropriate `Unpickler` for the subtype

Answer (score 0):

An example updated for play 2.5:

```
object TestContact extends App {

  sealed trait Shape

  object Shape {
    val rectFormat = Json.format[Rect]
    val circleFormat = Json.format[Circle]

    implicit object ShapeFormat extends Format[Shape] {
      override def writes(shape: Shape): JsValue = shape match {
        case rect: Rect =>
          Json.obj("Shape" ->
            Json.obj("Rect" ->
              Json.toJson(rect)(rectFormat)))
        case circle: Circle =>
          Json.obj("Shape" ->
            Json.obj("Circle" ->
              Json.toJson(circle)(circleFormat)))
      }

      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Shape] = {
        json \ "Shape" \ "Rect" match {
          case JsDefined(rectJson) => rectJson.validate[Rect](rectFormat)
          case _ => json \ "Shape" \ "Circle" match {
            case JsDefined(circleJson) => circleJson.validate[Circle](circleFormat)
            case _ => JsError("Not a valide Shape object.")
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }

  case class Rect(width: Double, height: Double) extends Shape

  case class Circle(radius: Double) extends Shape

  val circle = Circle(2.1)
  println(Json.toJson(circle))
  val rect = Rect(1.3, 8.9)
  println(Json.toJson(rect))

  var json = Json.obj("Shape" -> Json.obj("Circle" -> Json.obj("radius" -> 4.13)))
  println(json.validate[Shape])
  json =
    Json.obj("Shape" ->
      Json.obj("Rect" ->
        Json.obj("width" -> 23.1, "height" -> 34.7)))
  println(json.validate[Shape])
}
```